# Determine if list is subset of another list HQL

Tags: grails, hql

I'm trying to write a query for my Grails application that selects all the instances of `Apple` that are "related" to an instance of `Orange`.  Here the word "related" means all the instances of `Banana` that are associated with an instance of `Apple` are associated with some combination of instances of `Cherry` which are associated with the instance of `Orange` we are concerned with.  I have looked at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469575/hql-hibernate-how-to-check-if-a-list-of-elements-is-a-subset-of-another-list), but my query is a little more complex and I'm not seeing how to apply the given answer to my problem.

Here are the classes I'm dealing with:

```
class Apple {
    static hasMany = [ bananas: Banana ]
}

class Banana {
}

class Cherry {
    static hasMany = [ bananas: Bannna ]
}

class Orange {
    static hasMany = [ cherries: Cherry ]
}
```

In picture form that looks like this:

[image]

In the scenario 1 shown below, the desired query would only return "Apple 1" because all the instances of `Banana` that are related to "Apple 2" are not related to "Orange 1" through some combination of instances of "Cherry".

[image]

In the scenario 2 shown below, the desired query would return "Apple 1" and "Apple 2" because all the instances of `Banana` that are related to "Apple 2" are related to "Orange 1" through some combination of instances of "Cherry".

[image]

Here is the query I have been working with:

```
Apple.executeQuery(
    "SELECT DISTINCT apples
    FROM Apple apples
    INNER JOIN apples.banannas banannas
    WHERE banannas IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT banannas
        FROM Cherry cherries
        INNER JOIN cherries.banannas banannas
        WHERE cherries IN(
            SELECT DISTINCT cherries
            FROM Orange orange
            INNER JOIN orange.cherries cherries
            WHERE orange =:myOrange
        )
    )
    ORDER BY apples.id ASC",
    myOrange: myOrange
)
```

The problem is that my query returns "Apple 1" and "Apple 2" for both scenario 1 and 2.

**UPDATE #1:**

As requested, here is the SQL generated by the HQL query.  Sorry for the fruity obfuscation **<<< pun**

```
SELECT DISTINCT apple0_.id                     AS id10_,
                apple0_.version                AS version10_,
                apple0_.description            AS descript3_10_,
                apple0_.apple_priority_type_id AS apple4_10_,
                apple0_.apple_status_type_id   AS apple5_10_,
                apple0_.internal_need_date     AS internal6_10_,
                apple0_.name                   AS name10_
FROM   apple apple0_
       INNER JOIN apple_priority_type applepri1_
               ON apple0_.apple_priority_type_id = applepri1_.id
       INNER JOIN apple_status_type applesta2_
               ON apple0_.apple_status_type_id = applesta2_.id
       INNER JOIN apple_banana banana3_
               ON apple0_.id = banana3_.apple_bananas_id
       INNER JOIN banana banana4_
               ON banana3_.banana_id = banana4_.id
WHERE  banana4_.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT banana7_.id
                       FROM   cherry plum5_
                              INNER JOIN cherry_banana banana6_
                                      ON plum5_.id = banana6_.cherry_bananas_id
                              INNER JOIN banana banana7_
                                      ON banana6_.banana_id = banana7_.id
                       WHERE  plum5_.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT plum10_.id
                                            FROM   orange orange8_
                                                   INNER JOIN orange_cherry
                                                              plum9_
                                                           ON
orange8_.id = plum9_.orange_cherrys_id
INNER JOIN cherry plum10_
        ON
plum9_.cherry_id = plum10_.id
WHERE  orange8_.id = 248))
ORDER  BY apple0_.id ASC
LIMIT  100
```

**UPDATE #2:**

I actually have a way to make this work with HQL, but it isn't a nice one liner like I have in other places where I'm finding all of some type related to an instance of some other type.  Here is my work around:

```
    def bananas= myOrange.cherries.bananas.flatten().unique()
    def apples = Apple.getAll().collectMany{ !it.bananas.isEmpty() && bananas.containsAll( it.bananas ) ? [ it ] : [] }.flatten().unique()
    namedParams.put( "apples", apples )
    if( !apples.isEmpty() ) {
        apples = Apple.executeQuery( "SELECT DISTINCT apples FROM Apple apples WHERE apples IN(:apples) ${additionalQuery} ORDER BY ${sortname} ${sortorder}", namedParams )
    }
    return apples
```

Comment: Can you post the sql query produced by Hibernate?

Comment: @SérgioMichels Added generated SQL as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because if your Apple have at least one relation with a banana, will always return.

```
select
    distinct apple0_.id as id0_,
    apple0_.version as version0_ 
from
    apple apple0_ 
inner join
    apple_banana bananas1_ 
where bananas1_.banana_id in (1,2,3)
```

What you need to do is exclude from your results that apples where **not exists** a banana related with your Cherry. You will have to look if your database have a function like oracle **minus**.

**EDIT**: This query removes from the list that apples that have a banana that's not in the cherries bananas.

Note: I not checked the performance of this.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT apples
    FROM Apple apples
    INNER JOIN apples.bananas bananas
    WHERE bananas IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT bananas
        FROM Cherry cherries
        INNER JOIN cherries.bananas bananas
        WHERE cherries IN(
            SELECT DISTINCT cherries
            FROM Orange orange
            INNER JOIN orange.cherries cherries
            WHERE orange =:myOrange
        )
    )
  and apples not in (
    SELECT DISTINCT apples
      FROM Apple apples
     INNER JOIN apples.bananas bananas
      WHERE bananas NOT IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT bananas
          FROM Cherry cherries
          INNER JOIN cherries.bananas bananas
          WHERE cherries IN(
            SELECT DISTINCT cherries
            FROM Orange orange
            INNER JOIN orange.cherries cherries
            WHERE orange = :myOrange
          )
      )
    )
```

Comment: Right, but how do I make this work with an HQL one liner?  I actually have it working using mostly HQL, but it isn't as clean/efficient as I would like.  The function I have built to find all of a type associated with an instance of another type is assuming the query is going to be run using HQL so I can use pagination on the results. See update #2

Comment: Ok, I've updated with the query that's the result of what I mean with the "minus".